# Two figures in same graph, how to add mesh to figure 1 but not figure 2?

Tags: plotting, mesh

I plot two figures on the same graph. The following code adds mesh to both figures. But how do I add mesh to the first figure only (not to the second figure)?

```
ContourPlot3D[{z == x - 2 y, x^2 + y^2 == 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
  1}, {z, -3, 3}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5]], 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick], 
 Mesh -> {{1}}, MeshFunctions -> {#1^2 + #2^2 &}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
aa = ContourPlot3D[z == x - 2 y, 
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -3, 3}, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5]], 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick], 
  Mesh -> {{1}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1^2 + #2^2 &}];
bb = ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 1, 
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -3, 3},
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5]]];
Show[aa, bb]
```